# Accessing XML node values with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

I have an XML file with the following structure:

```xml
<FIELDS>
    <GRP1>
       <OPTION>
            <VALUE>71</VALUE>
            <CONTENT>Text</CONTENT>
       </OPTION>
       ...
       ...
    </GRP1>
    <GRP2>
       <OPTION>
            <VALUE>77</VALUE>
            <CONTENT>Test</CONTENT>
       </OPTION>
    </GRP2>
      ...
      ...
</FIELDS>
```

I need to get the node values of all child nodes of `<OPTIONS>` with `<GRP1>` as parent node.
I tried the following code but it did not work:

```js
// [...]
var xmlGRP = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(GRP1);
xmlvalue = xmlGRP.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
xmlcontent = xmlGRP.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` would return a node list. you have to traverse it using for loop or if there is only one element by that name, try using `xmlGRP[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Unless you have defined a variable called `GRP1`, that should be the string `'GRP1'`.
2. `xmlGRP` is directly a NodeList, not a Node; you don't need to look at a `childNodes` property on it.
3. Accessing numbered `childNodes` is unreliable due to potential differences in whitespace handling.
4. Accessing `firstChild` would fail for the case of empty string as the element would have no Text node child.

Try something like:

```
var grp1 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('GRP1')[0];
var firstOption = grp1.getElementsByTagName('OPTION')[0];
var value = firstOption.getElementsByTagName('VALUE')[0].textContent;
var content = firstOption.getElementsByTagName('CONTENT')[0].textContent;
```

(Note that `textContent` is a DOM Level 3 Core property that isn't supported by IE 8 and below. If you need to support that browser you could use a workalike, eg:)

```
function getTextContent(node) { // not 100% DOM3 compliant... good enough
    if ('textContent' in node)
        return node.textContent;
    var texts = [];
    for (child = node.firstChild; child!==null; child = child.nextSibling) {
        if (child.nodeType===1) // ELEMENT_NODE
            texts.push(getTextContent(child));
        else if (child.nodeType===3 || child.nodeType===4) // TEXT_NODE, CDATA_SECTION_NODE
            texts.push(child.data);
    }
    return texts.join('');
}
```